# How to change header URL after user logged in in Odoo 8/9?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-website

I am making a website on Odoo 9, extending website and web module, and creating a custom theme. I have added a few pages to the header of my website, and one of those is a Sign In page, in which a user can sign in my website.

My problem is that when the user logs in, the "Sign In" is still there, and I want this to change to "My Profile" page, for the user to handle its profile settings.

How can I check if user is logged and change the element in the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't website module already have a sign page? anyway, you can inherit website.layout to customize the website menu, try this :

```
<template id="custom_sign_in" customize_show="True" inherit_id="website.layout" name="Custom Sign In">
    <xpath expr="//ul[@id='top_menu']" position="inside">
        <li groups="base.group_public">
            <a t-attf-href="/web/YourSignInPage">
                <b>Custom Sign in</b>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li t-if="website.user_id != user_id">
            <a t-attf-href="/web/YourAccountPage">
                <b>Custom Account</b>
            </a>
        </li>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

I am using odoo 8, not sure if that will be suitable for odoo 9, let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, it worked, I got to this same solution yesterday. The website module does have a sign-in page, but I put another page before it to offer faceboook and google sign-in options. My solution was not exactly like yours, but the ideia is the same

Answer (score 1):

My solution was much like @SDBot one:

```
<template id="custom_header" inherit_id="website.layout" name="Custom Header">
    <xpath expr="//div[@id='wrapwrap']/header" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="id">my_header</attribute>
    </xpath>

    <xpath expr="//ul[@class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right']/li" position="before">
        <t t-if="user_id.partner_id.name == 'Public user'">
            <li>
                <a href="/page/website.signin">
                <span data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="3" data-oe-field="name" data-oe-type="char" data-oe-expression="submenu.name">SignUp</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </t>
        <t t-if="not user_id.partner_id.name == 'Public user'">
            <li>
                <a href="/page/website.profile">
                <span data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="3" data-oe-field="name" data-oe-type="char" data-oe-expression="submenu.name">My Profile</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </t>
    </xpath>
</template>
```